# Why can an arbitrary operator be linearized with a suitable basis?

Tags: group-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, linear-transformations

(Wu-Ki Tung, Group theory in physics, in proving the first Schur lemma) Let $A$ an arbitrary operator in space $V$. It can be made to be hermitian*, and a basis of the space can be chosen to consist of the eigenvectors $A$, i.e.

$$Au_{\alpha,i}=\lambda_iu_{\alpha,i}$$

Why does this always happen?

---

<sub>*Without loss of generality, we can take $A$ to be hermitian (if it's not, then it can be decomposed into two hermitian operators $A_+=(A-A^\dagger)/2, A_-=(A-A^\dagger)/2i$, consider each of them separately then combining them in $A=A_++iA_-$</sub>

Comment: I would look at the first 15 or so pages of Serre, *Linear Representations of Finite Groups*.

Comment: This is not true without more hypotheses on $A$; consider, for example, $A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan so A can't be any arbitrary operator?

Comment: No. But you don't need a statement like this to prove Schur's lemma anyway, at least some versions of it.

Comment: How do you make it Hermitian?

Comment: @user7530 Without loss of generality, we can take $A$ to be hermitian (if it's not, then it can be decomposed into two hermitian operators $A_+=(A-A^\dagger)/2, A_-=(A-A^\dagger)/2i$, consider each of them separately then combining them in $A=A_++iA_-$

Comment: Ok. You will need to explain what you mean by "arbitrary operator" and by "space." If $V$ is not a finite-dimensional vector space, you will need additional restrictions on $A$, e.g. that is bounded.

Comment: @user7530 what information do you need for the operator and space? The author simply states this in the process of proving Schur's lemma, without saying if $V$ is infinite-dimensional or not.